# Integrate just spits out the input

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Hi new to Mathematica here. I am trying to integrate this function. I am not so sure if it can be integrated or I have maybe messed up the syntax somewhere. I would be very happy for any help. The function is the first line after simplification. Thanks.

```
(-R^2 + r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t theta)/(R^4 - 
 2 R^2 r1 (r1 + d t theta) + r1^2 (r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t theta))

Integrate[%4, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> { R, r1, d, theta} \[Element] Reals && {R, r1, d} > 
    0 && -1 < theta < 1 ]
Integrate[(-R^2 + r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t theta)/(
 R^4 - 2 R^2 r1 (r1 + d t theta) + 
  r1^2 (r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t theta)), {t, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> (R | r1 | d | theta) \[Element] Reals && {R, r1, d} > 
    0 && -1 < theta < 1]
```

Comment: Version "12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" provides an answer for the second version of the integral after several minutes.  However, as @MichaelSeifert notes below, the result is quite complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [*Rubi*](https://rulebasedintegration.org) returns a result very quickly without needing your assumptions:

```
<< Rubi`

expr = (-R^2 + r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t theta)/(R^4 - 
     2 R^2 r1 (r1 + d t theta) + 
     r1^2 (r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t theta));

result = Int[expr, {t, 0, 1}]
```

```
1/r1^2 - (R^2 (1 - 2 theta^2) ArcTan[theta/Sqrt[1 - theta^2]])/(
 d r1^3 Sqrt[1 - theta^2]) - (
 R^2 (1 - 2 theta^2) ArcTan[(
   d r1 - (R^2 - r1^2) theta)/((R^2 - r1^2) Sqrt[1 - theta^2])])/(
 d r1^3 Sqrt[1 - theta^2]) - (R^2 theta Log[(R^2 - r1^2)^2])/(
 d r1^3) + (
 R^2 theta Log[
   d^2 r1^2 + (R^2 - r1^2)^2 - 2 d r1 (R^2 - r1^2) theta])/(d r1^3)
```

Then simplifying:

```
FullSimplify[result, R > 0 && r1 > 0 && d > 0 && -1 < theta < 1]
```

```
(1/(d r1^3 Sqrt[
 1 - theta^2]))(R^2 (-1 + 2 theta^2) ArcCot[((-R^2 + r1^2) Sqrt[
     1 - theta^2])/(R^2 theta - r1 (d + r1 theta))] + 
  R^2 (-1 + 2 theta^2) ArcSin[theta] + 
  Sqrt[1 - theta^2] (d r1 + 
     R^2 theta (-Log[(R^2 - r1^2)^2] + 
        Log[R^4 - 2 R^2 r1 (r1 + d theta) + 
          r1^2 (d^2 + r1^2 + 2 d r1 theta)])))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I think this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Even given the `Assumptions` in the question, the denominator of the integrand vanishes when `R = r1`.  This apparently gives Mathematica trouble.  We can get around this by calculating two distinct results, one for $R > r_1$ and one for $R < r_1$:

```
expr = (-R^2 + r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t theta)/(R^4 - 2 R^2 r1 (r1 + d t theta) + r1^2 (r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t theta))
result1 = Integrate[expr, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {R, r1, d} > 0 && -1 < theta < 1 && R > r1]
result2 = Integrate[expr, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {R, r1, d} > 0 && -1 < theta < 1 && R < r1]
```

The results returned by Mathematica are long and not worth reproducing here.  Notably, they include several imaginary terms, which should all cancel out in a real-valued integral.  Under the assumption that `theta` really stands for $\cos \theta$, we can induce Mathematica to get rid of them:

```
FullSimplify[result1 /. {Sqrt[1 - theta^2] -> Sin[th], theta -> Cos[th]}, 
  Assumptions -> {0 < th < \[Pi], R > r1 > 0, d > 0}]
```

[image]

This is still not optimally simplified (in particular, I would replace $\tan^{-1}(\cot(\theta)) \to \pi/2 - \theta$), but it's progress.